# Where do Adobe Stock images goto once purchased?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, stock-images

I am wondering where the file goes once purchased. It's already been at least a week, so the order should have went through and been confirmed.

I purchased an image on Adobe Stock a while back. Where will I find it? It's not showing up everywhere I look and can't find a useful outlet to voice this concern to them.

I don't want to have to call them. But if I'm simply missing a page where I goto collect the image, I'd love to know where that page is.

Comment: We aren't Adobe Stock tech support... you should contact them. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is taken from Adobe's Stock FAQs page:

> Adobe Stock can be launched from the Creative Cloud Libraries panel within CC applications, which currently include Photoshop CC, Illustrator CC, InDesign CC, Premiere Pro CC, After Effects CC, and Dreamweaver CC. Watermarked and licensed content from the Adobe Stock website can be saved directly to a Creative Cloud Library and is immediately available in your desktop and mobile applications. Adobe Stock content can also be licensed directly from the Creative Cloud Library in the desktop applications.

For more information, see [Using Adobe Stock](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/how-to/adobe-stock-creative-cloud-libraries.html).

Comment: This doesnt tell me where the images goto..

Comment: To your Adobe creative cloud library...?

Comment: This too I tried. I also tried on the forums and couldn't get any response yet.